# Get id's and add to array, delete from array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have the current .each in my javascript

```
var divs = array();
$('.div-item').each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   divs.push(id);
});
```

How would I delete an id from the array programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function deleteId(divArray, id) {
  var idx = $.inArray(id, divArray);
  if(idx != -1)
    divArray.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

**EDITED:** to use $.inArray: some versions of IE don't support the `indexOf` method on arrays.

Comment: So can it be deleteId(divs, "product_1");  ?

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Do you have a way i can chat with you have an offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [4,5,6];
list.splice(1, 1); // Remove one element, returns the removed ones.
```

list now equals [4,6]

Comment: is there a way for instance i want to remove 5 just do like .splice(5)? since i wouldn't know exactly the index of the value i want to remove?

Comment: See sje397's wrapper in his answer.